# How to add Toast message on button click in modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on React JS, I have a form which is opened in a modal, after submitting the form by clicking on the submit button I want to toast a success message that my form is successfully submitted.

here is my AddReview.js file where I made a modal which calls the PUT request on button click where it passes all the data to the backend

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import moment from "moment";
import axios from "axios";
import local from "../api/backendapi";
import "../scss/AddReviews.scss";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";

function AddReview({ closeAddModal, hotelId }) {
  const [rating, setRating] = useState();
  const [tripType, setTripType] = useState();
  const [checkInDate, setCheckInDate] = useState();
  const [summary, setSummary] = useState();
  const [details, setDetails] = useState();

  function Postrequest() {
    var data = JSON.stringify({
      checkInDate: checkInDate,
      rating: rating.value,
      tripType: tripType.value,
      title: summary,
      details: details,
    });
    console.log(data);
    var config = {
      method: "put",
      url: `${local}/hotel/${hotelId}/review`,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      data: data,
    };
    axios(config)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
        toast.success("Review added successfully!", {
        position: "top-right",
      autoClose: 5000,
      hideProgressBar: false,
      closeOnClick: true,
      pauseOnHover: false,
      draggable: true,
      progress: undefined,
    });
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
  const Date = "YYYY-MM-DD";
  const RATINGS = [
    { label: "EXCELLENT", value: "EXCELLENT" },
    { label: "GOOD", value: "GOOD" },
    { label: "AVERAGE", value: "AVERAGE" },
    { label: "POOR", value: "POOR" },
    { label: "TERRIBLE", value: "TERRIBLE" },
  ];
  return (
    <div>
      <MOModal id="mo-prompt" size="large">
        <MOModalHeader
          id="mo-prompt-header"
          title={"Add Hotel Review"}
          closeButton={true}
          onClose={closeAddModal}
        />
        <MOModalBody id="mo-prompt-body">
          <MOForm>
            <MOFormRow>
              <MOFormField id={"select-rating-field"} label={"Rating"}>
                <MOSelect
                  className={"input-box"}
                  placeholder={"Select rating you want to give"}
                  options={RATINGS}
                  value={rating}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setRating(e);
                  }}
                />
              </MOFormField>
            </MOFormRow>
            <MOFormRow>
              <MOFormField id={"review-summary-field"} label={"Summary"}>
                <input
                  className={"input-box"}
                  id={"review-summary-text-input"}
                  name={"summary"}
                  value={summary}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setSummary(e.target.value);
                  }}
                />
              </MOFormField>
            </MOFormRow>
          </MOForm>
        </MOModalBody>
        <MOModalFooter id="mo-prompt-footer">
          <MOButton
            className={"footer-btn"}
            id={"submit-review-btn"}
            type={"primary"}
            disabled={2 > 3 && true}
            onClick={Postrequest}
          >
            <i className="fa fa-paper-plane" />
            &nbsp; Submit
          </MOButton>

          <MOButton id="close-button" type="primary" onClick={closeAddModal}>
            <i className="fa fa-times" />
            &nbsp;Close
          </MOButton>
        </MOModalFooter>
      </MOModal>
    </div>
  );
}
export default AddReview;
```

The problem is I am unable to render the toast message on the modal, Can someone provide be some insights regarding it

Comment: Hi Karan. Is there any issue that you have stumbled upon, or ask a general question on how to achieve that?

Comment: I have edited and updated the question